# Can't download files from the downloadable products folder directly from the product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've created a few downloadable products and added an mp3 file as the product.

Now instead of going through the checkout to download the file i wanted the user to be able to do it on the products page in view.phtml by clicking on a link

The problem i have is that i can't seem to download files which are in this downloadable folder

```
    media/downloadable/files/links/t/o/toast_to_the_dead_-_immortal_technique.mp3
```

If i move that track to media/filename.mp3 ..or even in the wysiwyg folder then i can download it using my script. I've checked the file permissions etc and they're fine so im stuck as to why i can't download my files.

Does anyone know? or is there a way i can change the folder from downloadable to something else, as all i need downloadable products for is music files.

Cheers

Edit:
I should also add that i am getting the download box to save the file, with the correct file name and path, its just the file is 523 bytes, im using the code below to get the filepath

```
    $mediaUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $_linkpath = $mediaUrl."downloadable/files/links".$_link->getLinkFile();
```

If i were to change the link path to $mediaUrl."filename.mp3" etc then it would download..so seems to me that its the downloadable folder thats causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I've solved this, I just changed $_linkpath to

```
   $_linkpath = "media/downloadable/files/links".$_link->getLinkFile();
```

The full url was causing the problem